# Debug cpu usage (any process) on Device possible?

Tags: android, process, cpu-usage

Im wondering that there are a few apps in market, which show the cpu usage for each process.
I dont know how they get this infos. Anybody knows that?

The only solution i know is to read /proc//stat for any process, so I need Jiffies/ms and sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK).

I parsed Jiffies via /proc/timer_list but i dont know where to get sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK).